# Do AppEngine-Go modules have to share the same code base

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The canonical example given for appengine-go module uploads implies that all modules within a given app must share the same codebase.

e.g. appcfg update app.yaml mobile-frontend.yaml my-module.yaml

In this case, all Go files in the app root directory are processed identically for each module (and therefore share the same code).

Is there any way to specify a separate root directory for each module e.g. as a sub-directory of the default app root?

TIA

Comment: Actually, just found what I was looking for [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-go/T90jtkZ83s4/MizIcnjH4QIJ)

Comment: the link you posted is the most straight forward answer I have ever seen for this problem.  You should post an answer for your question (including the link).

Answer (score 2):

As a new SO user, I was restricted by the 8-hour limit for answering my own question. Therefore I posted it initially as a comment.

So here is the link in question for anyone who runs into this problem:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-go/T90jtkZ83s4/MizIcnjH4QIJ

As an aside, the new modules paradigm is vital for GAE projects. Not only does it allow for different code bases for each module but also different runtimes!!!

This means that, theoretically at least, you can leverage the best features of each language within the same app. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Finally got my app working in development and on App Engine. Thanks. To summarize the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728789/1302813):

My app directory looks like this:

```
$ ls *
README.md   dispatch.yaml

frontend:
app.yaml    index.html  server.go

images:
images.yaml server.go
```

Then to run in development:

```
$ goapp serve dispatch.yaml */*.yaml
```

and to deploy:

```
$ appcfg.py update_dispatch .
$ goapp deploy */*.yaml
```

[Source code.](https://github.com/baruchlubinsky/fractalserver/tree/861c779c1c401084303d44267e512f170851d354)